# Cartesian Product of Algebras forms an Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Consider the ring $A$ and let $B$ and $C$ be $A$-algebras.

I was asked to prove on an old homework assignment that the ring $B \times C$ is an $A$-algebra.

From Atiyah and MacDonald, I have the following definition:

> Let $f: A \longrightarrow B$ be a ring homomorphism.  If $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, define the product $ab = f(a)b$.  An $A$-*algebra* is a ring $B$ together with a ring homomorphism $f$.

Since $B$ and $C$ are $A$-algebras, then we can define the ring homomorphisms $f: A \longrightarrow B$ with product $ab = f(a)b$ and $g: A \longrightarrow C$ with product $ac = g(a)c$.

Where do I go from here?  What do elements of an $A$-algebra "look like"?

Comment: Given $f: A \to B$ and $g: A \to C$ we can define $h: A \to B \times C$ by $h(a)=(f(a),g(a))$. Hence the multiplication would look like $a(b,c)=(f(a)b,g(a)c)$. Does that help?

Comment: @leibnewtz Yes.  So the $A-algebra$ is the ring homomorphism $h$ along with the ring $B \times C$?

Comment: Yes, are you familiar with the ring structure on $B \times C$?

Comment: Yes, it is an ordered pair $(b,c)$ where $b \in B$ and $c \in C$

Comment: Those are the elements of the ring, but in general addition is given by $(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+b,c+d)$ and multiplication by $(a,b)(c,d)=(ac,bd)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the elements of a direct product $B \times C$ of two rings $B$ and $C$ are elements in the Cartesian product $B \times C$, i.e. sets of the form $(b,c)$, where $b \in B$ and $c \in C$.

If we are given ring homomorphisms $f: A \to B$ and $g: A \to C$, it is straightforward to check that the map $h: A \to B \times C$ given by $h(a)=(f(a),g(a))$ is a ring homomorphism (try it yourself).

Hence given your definition of an algebra, the direct product $B \times C$ inherits an algebra structure from $B$ and $C$ given by the multiplication $a(b,c)= (f(a)b, g(a)c)$. So the algebra $B \times C$ is the ring $B \times C$ together with the homomorphism $h: A \to B \times C$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!